# How do you select the pivot of the edit camera?

Tags: camera, edit-mode, vertices

All I find when i try to search this question is how to move the rendering camera, not the editor.

Blender's editor camera focuses on the center, I need to change that to focus on a vertex, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'viewport' pivot point can be positioned easily be simply hitting <kbd>.</kbd> on the numberic keypad. To set the pivot to the vertex of a mesh simply enter Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select the vertex (right-click it) and hit <kbd>.</kbd> on the numeric keypad.

Another useful shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to set the view pivot point to the current location of the 3D Cursor.

Comment: What if i need to center it at the cursor?

Comment: Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> for that. See the View|Align View menu in the 3D View menu bar.

Comment: For Blender 2.8 *Alt+Home* is now *Alt+MMB* (windows)